# Sliding up Panel should slide up on a button click. Using the open source SlidingUpPanel from Umano App on GitHub

Tags: android, github

Hey I use the Sliding up Panel which is an open source on GitHub from the Umano App.
I implemented it in my app and it is working. -> When you click on the panel or drag on it then it slide up.

But I want that it slide up whe I click on a specific button.

Has anyone experience with this sliding panel and can help me?

Heres the open code: [SlidingUpPanel on GitHub](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: Can you able to add LinearLayout as first child?? I tried and its showing null pointer exception in Graphical Layout.

Answer (score 17):

This should work:

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout  layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

layout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
```

Comment: that's very strange, wich version of the library are you using? I took those lines from my code and for me it works

Comment: Works for me, but the slide animation is too fast. The panel looks like it jumps to the middle of the screen before sliding.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD you should add the first line to your "onStart" method, and the second line into your button's "onClickListener", the code won't just work on its own :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<Button 
 android:id="@+id/close_SlidingUpPanel"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

And in your java code:

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_up_panel);
layout.setDragView(findViewById(R.id.close_SlidingUpPanel));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

SlidingUpPanelLayout **layout**;

**layout** = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

When you want to expand the Panel put:

**layout.expandPane();**

and when you try to collapse the Panel put:

**layout.collapsePane();**

Comment: there is no method expandPane()

Comment: you're confusing this library with SlidingPaneLayout, it works only there.